# How to hold hidden div on button click event as right now it gets disappear quickely

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In following code, when I click button it shows div with id addnew2 but it will get disappear quickely. Help me out. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").ready(function(){
        $("#addnew2").hide();
    });
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#addnew2").show();
    });
});
</script>

<body id="hide">
    <form>
        <div id="demo">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add"/>
        </div>
        <div id="addnew2">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add1"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$("#hide").ready(function(){
$("#addnew2").hide();
});
```

with just this:

```
$("#addnew2").hide();
```

Because a `div` element does not fire a *ready* event. In fact, jQuery just interprets it as representing the *ready* event on the document.

You should also return *false* to cancel the click event:

```
return false;
```

If the click event is not cancelled, your form will get submitted, which results in a refresh of the page, and hides the second button again.

It works in this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addnew2").hide();
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#addnew2").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="hide">
    <form>
        <div id="demo">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add"/>
        </div>
        <div id="addnew2">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" id="add1"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: still after clicking ob button the div show and it will get disapper quickly

Comment: Then you have something else in your page that is acting on this button. See the snippet in my answer: it works.

Comment: this might work in Chrome, but as the OP said, as soon as you click submit for the first button, the second one shows up, but disappears soon after in FF.

Comment: @trincot very strange. I even used `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>` and it reacts the same. Very very strange.

Comment: Probably the form is submitted with the first click which would redisplay the original page. So `return false` added to my answer.

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks a bunch for mentioning it, @Fred-ii-. I see you a lot around, and appreciate your contributions!

Comment: @trincot Always a pleasure ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: I wonder if the `.ready()` event is legitimate for non DOCUMENT objects? I thought it only applies to the DOM.

Comment: @Terry, indeed, I don't think it is. I did not find any documented use of it on anything else than *document*. I think jQuery ignores the selector in `$(....).ready`. I noticed that if you have two handlers like that, they will execute in order, independent of the selector you have used.